Anchor: Cargo Build Failed to install platform-tools
I get this error when running anchor test:
**uanadev@DESKTOP-ED77BQ8:~/workspace/temp-project$ anchor test
[2024-09-11T00:53:29.312271366Z ERROR cargo_build_sbf] Failed to install platform-tools: Unable to write "/home/uanadev/.cache/solana/v1.41/platform-tools/tmp-platform-tools-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2": Custom { kind: Other, error: reqwest::Error { kind: Body, source: hyper::Error(Body, Custom { kind: UnexpectedEof, error: IncompleteBody }) } }**

I have no idea what to do about it. Saw someone with a similar issue at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/issues/31060, though the item which had failed to install was a different one. The fix for the issue was to manually install the sbf and untar it, but I do not know how to manually install this platform-tool nor if this even is the fix for my problem.
Does anyone know how to install this platform-tool or if there is another fix for this problem?
I'm on Windows 11, WSL: Ubuntu.

This might be related to a network issue. What versions of anchor and Solana CLI are you running ?

@Jimii
When I run solana --version: solana-cli 1.18.23 (src:e5d267d9; feat:4215500110, client:Agave)
anchor --version: anchor-cli 0.30.1
cargo --version: cargo 1.81.0 (2dbb1af80 2024-08-20)
rustc --version: rustc 1.81.0 (eeb90cda1 2024-09-04)

I retried it now and something entirely different is happening:
uanadev@DESKTOP-ED77BQ8:~/workspace$ anchor init temp-project
Error: yarn install failed: No such file or directory (os error 2) < this happened before
uanadev@DESKTOP-ED77BQ8:~/workspace$ ls
Rust-Tutorial  temp-project
uanadev@DESKTOP-ED77BQ8:~/workspace$ cd temp-project/
uanadev@DESKTOP-ED77BQ8:~/workspace/temp-project$ anchor test
error: not a directory: '/home/uanadev/.local/share/solana/install/releases/stable-e5d267d92a4d6d0b61d249440d178d5694d8f48e/solana-release/bin/sdk/sbf/dependencies/platform-tools/rust/lib'

I managed to fix it.
After going into .local/share/solana/install/releases/stable-e5d267d92a4d6d0b61d249440d178d5694d8f48e/solana-release/bin/sdk/sbf/dependencies/platform-tools/, I found the file tmp-platform-tools-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2.
It occurred to me something must have gone wrong during installation so I reinstalled solana-cli and anchor-cli, installed yarn and then ran cargo build-sbf --force-tools-install in my project file. That seemed to have done the job.

I downgrade solana client to 1.18.12
using
agave-install 1.18.12
it worked fine

I was getting this error while running the hello world in the soon svm following this turorial: https://github.com/soonlabs/hello-world  and this is how I have solved it.
From 2. after cd src/program-rust, I ran yarn or npm i or pnpm i which installed the dependencies in this directory and then ran cargo build-sbf which ran the program without errors.
